# sorting and filtering not working in custom admin module

Tags: magento, module, grid

I am trying to implement an admin module in magento which has a grid in the first page and grids in the tabs while editing the grid entities.

The main grid works fine, but the grids in the tabs are not working fine.

The problem I found while I debugged the code is that, I am loading the collection in the grid with field filtering, ie I am filtering the collection with filter that is the user id. I did this because I need only data of a single user from the table. This made the entire problem, the data in the grid is coming correctly, but the filtering,sorting and searching feature inside grid is not working and returning a 404 not found error page. I tried removing the field filter I added while getting the collection, then it works fine but all the data in the table is coming which is the opposite to my requirement. 
Is there any possible solution to this. Here is the way I am trying to do:

```
protected function _prepareCollection() {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('merchant/subscriptions')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('user_id', Mage::registry('merchant_data')->getId());
        $this->setCollection($collection); //Set the collection
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok My problem is solved there is a mistake in my code. In the grid file the function below was wrong.

```
 public function getGridUrl() {
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/transactiongrid', array('user_id',Mage::registry('merchant_data')->getId(), '_current' => true));
}
```

The correct method was

```
 public function getGridUrl() {
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/transactiongrid', array('user_id'=> Mage::registry('merchant_data')->getId(), '_current' => true));
}
```

Comment: What is the difference in both functions which you have written in your answer?

Comment: in the paremeter I passed after 'user_id' I added comma first actually it must be '=>'. This function takes two parameters and i passed three.

Answer (score 1):

Filter action is dependent on your below method:

```
public function getGridUrl() {
  return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('user_id' => Mage::registry('merchant_data')->getId(),'_current'=>true));
}
```

now this is how you will prepare collection:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $regData = Mage::registry('merchant_data');
    if(isset($regData))
              $regData = $regData->getId();
    else
       $regData = $this->getRequest()->getParam('user_id');
    $collection = Mage::getModel('merchant/subscriptions')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('user_id',$regData);
...
```

Comment: there is one problem though.The 404 not found error is not coming now,
but the results when after sorting, filtering and searching returns null. What will be causing this @Deependra Singh

Comment: you can check you `*/*/grid` action, then in `_prepareCollection()` confirm that you are getting $regData correctly every time.

Comment: The regData is coming correctly it is having the value of userid. I am calling the actions transactiongrid and subscriptiongrid for grids which i have written in my controller.

Comment: public function getGridUrl() {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/transactiongrid', array('user_id', Mage::registry('merchant_data')->getId(), '_current' => true));
    }
This is the action written in controller:

public function transactiongridAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(
                $this->getLayout()->createBlock('merchant/adminhtml_merchant_edit_tab_transactiongrid')->toHtml()
        );
    }

Comment: that seems fine to me. So then $regData might be going blank or wrong. you should dump it and check. and First try my updated answer if it help.

Comment: When I used: if(isset($regData->getId())) I am getting a blank page now.

Comment: allright keep the earlier code but to check that during ajax filter values are going in correct way.check that your ajax path has correct parameter and then place `echo "Data:".$regData;die;` just before passing value to collection statement and check in Firebug console that are getting correct response. I dont have any doubt on suggested code bcz I've been using same code in a module

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43239/discussion-between-deependra-singh-and-akash-pius)

Answer (score 0):

When I dumped $regData I got this:

```
Cubet_Merchant_Model_Merchant Object
(
    [_eventPrefix:protected] => core_abstract
    [_eventObject:protected] => object
    [_resourceName:protected] => merchant/merchant
    [_resource:protected] => 
    [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => merchant/merchant_collection
    [_cacheTag:protected] => 
    [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1
    [_isObjectNew:protected] => 
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 3
            [firstname] => Robin
            [lastname] => Cubet
            [email] => robin@cubettech.com
            [username] => robincubet
            [password] => 51a7f45eb11fc49b5967a0039193c3ad:HSX8JkSO5lr3uaRHrzd86i7gb0RATeDb
            [created] => 2013-12-12 08:34:28
            [modified] => 2013-12-16 09:03:56
            [logdate] => 
            [lognum] => 0
            [reload_acl_flag] => 1
            [is_active] => 1
            [extra] => N;
            [rp_token] => 
            [rp_token_created_at] => 
        )

    [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 
    [_origData:protected] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 3
            [firstname] => Robin
            [lastname] => Cubet
            [email] => robin@cubettech.com
            [username] => robincubet
            [password] => 51a7f45eb11fc49b5967a0039193c3ad:HSX8JkSO5lr3uaRHrzd86i7gb0RATeDb
            [created] => 2013-12-12 08:34:28
            [modified] => 2013-12-16 09:03:56
            [logdate] => 
            [lognum] => 0
            [reload_acl_flag] => 1
            [is_active] => 1
            [extra] => N;
            [rp_token] => 
            [rp_token_created_at] => 
        )

    [_idFieldName:protected] => user_id
    [_isDeleted:protected] => 
    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```